# How to determine success of ScriptBlock?

Tags: powershell

I want to know if a `ScriptBlock` executed successfully.

If I run

```
1/0; echo $?
```

I get

```
RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero.
false
```

but if I do

```
$s = { 1/0 }; Invoke-Command $s; echo $?
```

I get

```
RuntimeException: Attempted to divide by zero.
true
```

I assume that `$?` is referring to the execution of `Invoke-Command`, but how can I get success of the script block itself?

I don't need to use `Invoke-Command`, if changing to `$s.Invoke()` is viable then happily use that.

---

**Context**

I want to write a function for a DSL along the likes of

```
function at_place {
    Param(
        [string] $Path,
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    )

    Push-Location $Path ;

    Invoke-Command $ScriptBlock ;
    # following line doesn't work        
    [bool] $ScriptBlockPass = $? ;
    
    If ( $? ){
        Write-Debug "success!" ;
        Pop-Location ;
    } Else {
        Write-Error "ScriptBlock failed, remaining at $Path, please fix manually." ;
        throw "ScriptBlock failed at $Path" ;
    }
}
```

I have things in my buffer like

```
Push-Location ~/foo; doStuff; If ( $? ){ Pop-Location; } Else { Write-Error "Failed, fix here" }
```

Which I would like to write as

```
at_place ~/foo { doStuff; }
```

My *actual* change is about using Git to ignore a bunch of files, stash them, apply some edits, and then reignore them etc. Simplified here hopefully to be more broadly applicable and less distracting.

Comment: Define "successfully", no terminating errors? no non-terminating errors? no warnings? Aside, `Invoke-Command` is not meant to invoke scriptblocks locally

Comment: `$s = { 1/0; $? }`

Comment: @js2010 Yes, I had thought of that before and it's ugly because it requires the script block writers to remember it each time, and it's not transparent. This is basically for a DSL so aesthetics matter here.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon is `$s.Invoke()` appropriate here? I guess 'successfully' as in "what was the value of `$?` the last command run from the script block.

Comment: It's not a script terminating exception, unless $ErrorActionPreference -eq 'stop'

Comment: Script terminating:  `$s = { throw }`

Comment: The same discussion could be had over defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad and the answer is, it really depends.

Child scope invocations can only update the value of `$?` via [`$PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) using either [`.WriteError` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeerror?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-writeerror(system-management-automation-errorrecord)) or [`.ThrowTerminatingError` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet.throwterminatingerror?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-cmdlet-throwterminatingerror(system-management-automation-errorrecord)) as stated in the [about Automatic Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#section-1) documentation. This would imply that the script block or function is an [advanced one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$s = {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    try {
        1 / 0
    }
    catch {
        $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
    }
}

& $s # Writes Error
$?   # Value will be False (Failure)
```

For a non-advanced function or script block, `$?` would be categorized as unreliable, one way to know if the script block succeeded (and by succeeded I mean it had no errors) and, in my opinion, the most reliable one, would be to set the error preference to `Stop` to target both, terminating an non terminating errors and execute the script block in a [try / catch / finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$s = { Write-Error foo }

try {
    $previousPreference = $ErrorActionPreference
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    & $s
}
catch {
    'had errors'
}
finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = $previousPreference
}
```

As for the new edit, I would approach your function this way:

```
function at_place {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string] $Path,
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock
    )

    try {
        $sbSuccess = $true
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
        $pushSuccess = Push-Location $Path -PassThru
        & $ScriptBlock
    }
    catch {
        $sbSuccess = $false
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
    }
    finally {
        if($pushSuccess -and $sbSuccess) {
            Pop-Location
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my edit to the question may add the context to narrow it down.

Comment: @Sled I think that edit might work for your use case. This definitely only covers native PowerShell. Does not cover executing of external commands inside the scriptblock. For that you want to check `$LASTEXITCODE`.